# SoX: Can I generate simultaneous sounds?

Tags: bash, sox

I use SoX to generate this sound:

```
$ play -n synth 1 pluck E3 repeat 2
```

I manage to play simultaneously another pattern a new terminal tab, let’s say `$ play -n synth 1.5 pluck C3 repeat 2` in. Is there a way to both patterns in the same bash script, simultaneously?

Comment: You should always be able to launch multiple programs simultaneously with `&`. But are you sure that `bash` is the most appropriate tool for the task? I mean, even carefully engineered languages like Chuck and packages like Alda are still somewhat cumbersome to use, I don't think that bash can compete with those... You've certainly [looked through this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_audio_programming_languages)?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes I am sure I want to use the simplest sound generator as possible for this project. I thought about using `beep` but it is too low level. When you advise to use `&`, do you mean this way `play -n synth 4 pluck 200 & play -n synth 4 pluck 100` ? Because it doesn’t play both sounds unfortunately.

Comment: You are missing semicolons there, it's not supposed to separate the commands, but rather be appended to a command. Look at `&` as used in [the last example 21-3 "Running parallel processes in subshells" here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html). But I'm not sure how this `play` command reacts to this: it might turn out that `play` only enqueues commands to a single local server-instance, and that it doesn't work in parallel.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin This is incorrect, any of `;`, `&`, `&&` and `||` may be used to separate commands. `;` and `&` have precedence over `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @xhienne What is "this" that is "incorrect" that you are referring to? Nobody asked how to separate commands, the `&` above was proposed for launching multiple processes in parallel, not for separating commands. None of `;`, `&`, `&&`, `||` (when used as separator) have anything to do with launching processes in parallel. Moreover, the question is from March... I have no clue what it's all about.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I was referring to your first sentence "You are missing semicolons there, it's not supposed to separate the commands, but rather be appended to a command". This is incorrect: there is no missing semicolon, `&` may be used to separate commands as rooofl did and `&' actually put the preceding command in background, effectively launching it in parallel to the next command.

Comment: @xhienne `(sleep 2 ; echo "right") & (sleep 1; echo "you are")`

Answer (score 5):

This would accomplish what you need, playing E3 on the left channel and C3 on the right channel:

```
$ play -n synth 1 pluck E3 pluck C3 repeat 2
```

If you want both notes played on both channels then add the channels effect:

```
$ play -n synth 1 pluck E3 pluck C3 repeat 2 channels 1
```

Excerpt from SoX manual, **synth** effect in
http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

> ... Multiple synth effects can be cascaded to produce more complex waveforms;...

Answer (score 2):

To address your specific issue running two `play` commands simultaneously in the same terminal, here is an explanation and a workaround to what happens when you bind your two commands with `&`:

```
$ play -n synth 1 pluck E3 & play -n synth 1 pluck E3
[1] 15682

(snipped information about audio file)

In:0.00% 00:00:01.02 [00:00:00.00] Out:48.0k [      |      ] Hd:0.0 Clip:0
Done.

[1]+  Stopped                 play -n synth 1 pluck E3
$ fg
play -n synth 1 pluck E3
In:0.00% 00:00:01.02 [00:00:00.00] Out:48.0k [      |      ] Hd:0.0 Clip:0  
Done.
```

See the `[1]+  Stopped` line? It means that your first `play` process was put to sleep. That's the reason why I had to run `fg` to wake it up and bring it to the foreground.

Why was it stopped? Because the first `play` command tried to read or write something to the terminal, which is only allowed to a foreground process (the second `play` command). As a background process, it received either a SIGTTIN or a SIGTTOU signal which forced it to stop.

How to work around this? By preventing the background `play` to read and write anything to the terminal:

```
play -n synth 1 pluck E3 < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 & { sleep 0.5; play -n synth 1 pluck E3; }
```

The `--no-show-progress` (`-q`) and `-V0` options seem sufficient, although I cannot assure you this will work in every situation, contrary to the above command:

```
play -q -V0 -n synth 1 pluck E3 & { sleep 0.5; play -n synth 1 pluck E3; }
```